# Is there a better way to parse the following xml using BeautifulSoup that returns everything in an organized panda table?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse and xml file. I have been able to successfully parse all the levels up the text column. My code is only returning the last item per paragraph in the xml instead of returning all the items in their respective row.

**The following is the chunk of the code I am having trouble with:**

```py
        # Rest of text
        article_text = ""
        alinea = article.find_all("ALINEA")
        
        ****** I believe the problem starts here ******
        
        for index, p in enumerate(alinea, 1):
            txt = p.find_all("TXT")
            if p.find_previous_sibling():
                # Captures Alinea text of parent
                if p.find_previous_sibling().name == "NO.PARAG":
                    # Used for main text of paragraph
                    if p.contents[0].name == "P":
                        article_text = p.contents[0].text
                        c8 = c7 + '.' + p.find_previous_sibling().text.replace('.', '')
                        parent_citation = c8
                # used for definitions -- do not have a "NO.PARAG" before ALINEA
                article_text = p.text
        txt = p.find_all("TXT")
        for index, t in enumerate(txt, 1):
            if p.find_previous_sibling():
                if t.find_previous_sibling().name == 'NO.P':
                    citation_level_8 = parent_citation + p.find_previous_sibling().text
                    article_text = t.text

        lst.append([t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7,
                    c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, 
                    article_text])
```

**The following is my CURRENT outcome:**

| t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | t6 | t7 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 |  | Article 1 : Paragraph 3 Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 2 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 |  | Article 2 : Paragraph 4 Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Definitions |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 3 |  | (3) text |

**The following is my DESIRED outcome:**

| t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | t6 | t7 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 | Article 1.1 | Article 1 : Paragraph 1 Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 | Article 1.1(a) | (a) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 | Article 1.1(i) | (a) text **(line break)** (i) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 | Article 1.1(ii) | (a) text **(line break)** (ii) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 | Article 1.1(b) | (b) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 1 | Article 1.2 | Article 1 : Paragraph 2 Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 2 | Article 2.1 | Article 2 : Paragraph 1 Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 2 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 2 | Article 2.1(a) | (a) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 2 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 2 | Article 2.1(b) | (b) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 2 | Article 2.2 | Article 2 : Paragraph 2 Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 2 | Article 2.3 | Article 2 : Paragraph 3 Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Article 1 Title |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 2 | Article 2.3(a) | (a) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Definitions |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 3 |  | Article 3: Definitions Main Text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Definitions |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 3 | Article 3(1) | Article 3: Definitions Main Text **(line break)** (1) text |
|  |  | Chapter I Title |  |  | Definitions |  |  | Chapter I |  |  | Article 3 | Article 3(2) | Article 3: Definitions Main Text **(line break)** (2) text |

**The following is the xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DIVISION>
   <TITLE>
      <TI>
         <P>
            <HT TYPE="ITALIC">CHAPTER I</HT>
         </P>
      </TI>
      <STI>
         <P>
            <HT TYPE="BOLD">
               <HT TYPE="ITALIC">Chapther I Title</HT>
            </HT>
         </P>
      </STI>
   </TITLE>
   <ARTICLE IDENTIFIER="001">
      <TI.ART>Article 1</TI.ART>
      <STI.ART>Article 1 Title</STI.ART>
      <PARAG IDENTIFIER="001.001">
         <NO.PARAG>1.</NO.PARAG>
         <ALINEA>
            <P>Article 1 : Paragraph 1 Main Textt</P>
            <LIST TYPE="alpha">
               <ITEM>
                  <NP>
                     <NO.P>(a)</NO.P>
                     <TXT>(a) Text</TXT>
                     <P>
                        <LIST TYPE="roman">
                           <ITEM>
                              <NP>
                                 <NO.P>(i)</NO.P>
                                 <TXT>(i) text</TXT>
                              </NP>
                           </ITEM>
                           <ITEM>
                              <NP>
                                 <NO.P>(ii)</NO.P>
                                 <TXT>(ii) text</TXT>
                              </NP>
                           </ITEM>
                        </LIST>
                     </P>
                  </NP>
               </ITEM>
               <ITEM>
                  <NP>
                     <NO.P>(b)</NO.P>
                     <TXT>(b) text</TXT>
                  </NP>
               </ITEM>
            </LIST>
         </ALINEA>
      </PARAG>
      <PARAG IDENTIFIER="001.002">
         <NO.PARAG>2.</NO.PARAG>
         <ALINEA>Article 1 : Paragraph 2 Main Text</ALINEA>
      </PARAG>
   </ARTICLE>
   <ARTICLE IDENTIFIER="002">
      <TI.ART>Article 2</TI.ART>
      <STI.ART>Article 2 Title</STI.ART>
      <PARAG IDENTIFIER="002.001">
         <NO.PARAG>1.</NO.PARAG>
         <ALINEA>
            <P>Article 2 : Paragraph 1 Main Text</P>
            <LIST TYPE="alpha">
               <ITEM>
                  <NP>
                     <NO.P>(a)</NO.P>
                     <TXT>(a) text;</TXT>
                  </NP>
               </ITEM>
               <ITEM>
                  <NP>
                     <NO.P>(b)</NO.P>
                     <TXT>(b) text</TXT>
                  </NP>
               </ITEM>
            </LIST>
         </ALINEA>
      </PARAG>
      <PARAG IDENTIFIER="002.002">
         <NO.PARAG>2.</NO.PARAG>
         <ALINEA>Article 2 : Paragraph 2 Main Text.</ALINEA>
      </PARAG>
      <PARAG IDENTIFIER="002.003">
         <NO.PARAG>3.</NO.PARAG>
         <ALINEA>
            <P>Article 2 : Paragraph 3 Main Text</P>
            <LIST TYPE="alpha">
               <ITEM>
                  <NP>
                     <NO.P>(a)</NO.P>
                     <TXT>(a) text</TXT>
                  </NP>
               </ITEM>
            </LIST>
         </ALINEA>
      </PARAG>
      <PARAG IDENTIFIER="002.004">
         <NO.PARAG>4.</NO.PARAG>
         <ALINEA>Article 2 : Paragraph 4 Main Text</ALINEA>
      </PARAG>
   </ARTICLE>
   <ARTICLE IDENTIFIER="003">
      <TI.ART>Article 3</TI.ART>
      <STI.ART>Definitions</STI.ART>
      <ALINEA>
         <P>Article 3: Definitions Main Text</P>
         <LIST
            TYPE="ARAB">
            <ITEM>
               <NP>
                  <NO.P>(1)</NO.P>
                  <TXT>(1) text</TXT>
               </NP>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
               <NP>
                  <NO.P>(2)</NO.P>
                  <TXT>(2) text</TXT>
               </NP>
            </ITEM>
         </LIST>
      </ALINEA>
   </ARTICLE>
</DIVISION>
```

**The following is ALL of my current code**

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def determine_level(bs4_object):
    if "subsection" in bs4_object.find('TI').text.lower():
        c6 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("TI").text)
        if (bs4_object.find("STI") is not None):
            t6 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("STI").text)
            return 6, c6, t6
        return 6, c6, ''

    elif "sub-section" in bs4_object.find('TI').text.lower():
        c6 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("TI").text)
        if (bs4_object.find("STI") is not None):
            t6 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("STI").text)
            return 6, c6, t6
        return 6, c6, ''

    elif "section" in bs4_object.find('TI').text.lower():
        c5 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("TI").text)
        if (bs4_object.find("STI") is not None):
            t5 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("STI").text)
            return 5, c5, t5
        return 5, c5, ''

    elif "chapter" in bs4_object.find('TI').text.lower():
        c4 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("TI").text)
        if (bs4_object.find("STI") is not None):
            t4 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("STI").text)
            return 4, c4, t4
        return 4, c4, ''

    elif "title" in bs4_object.find('TI').text.lower():
        c3 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("TI").text)
        if (bs4_object.find("STI") is not None):
            t3 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("STI").text)
            return 3, c3, t3
        return 3, c3, ''

    elif "part" in bs4_object.find('TI').text.lower():
        c2 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("TI").text)
        if (bs4_object.find("STI") is not None):
            t2 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bs4_object.find("STI").text)
            return 2, c2, t2
        return 2, c2, ''
    else:
        "Cannot be determined"


def scrape_file():

    #   Reading data from the xml file
    with open('./info.xml', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()

    info_data = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

    articles = info_data.find_all("ARTICLE")
    lst = []

    for index, article in enumerate(articles):

        c2 = None
        t2 = None
        c3 = None
        t3 = None
        c4 = None
        t4 = None
        c5 = None
        t5 = None
        c6 = None
        t6 = None
        t7 = None
        c7 = None
        c8 = None

        # Article level 7
        c7 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", article.find("TI.ART").text)
        if article.find("STI.ART"):
            t7 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", article.find("STI.ART").text)

        # Determining the number and levels of parents
        article_parents = article.findParents('DIVISION')
        for parent in reversed(article_parents):
            level_determined = determine_level(parent)

            if level_determined is None:
                continue

            elif 2 == level_determined[0]:
                c2 = level_determined[1].title()
                t2 = level_determined[2].capitalize()

            elif 3 == level_determined[0]:
                c3 = level_determined[1].split(" ")[0].capitalize() + ' ' + \
                    level_determined[1].split(" ")[1]
                citations = (c2, c3)
                c3 = ', '.join(str(citation)
                               for citation in citations if citation is not None)
                t3 = level_determined[2].capitalize()

            elif 4 == level_determined[0]:
                c4 = level_determined[1].split(" ")[0].capitalize() + ' ' + \
                    level_determined[1].split(" ")[1]
                citations = (c3, c4)
                c4 = ', '.join(str(citation)
                               for citation in citations if citation is not None)
                t4 = level_determined[2].capitalize()

            elif 5 == level_determined[0]:
                c5 = level_determined[1].split(" ")[0].capitalize() + ' ' + \
                    level_determined[1].split(" ")[1]
                citations = (c4, c5)
                c5 = ', '.join(str(citation)
                               for citation in citations if citation is not None)
                t5 = level_determined[2].capitalize()

            elif 6 == level_determined[0]:
                c6 = level_determined[1].split(" ")[0].capitalize() + ' ' + \
                    level_determined[1].split(" ")[1]
                citations = (c5, c6)
                c6 = ', '.join(str(citation)
                               for citation in citations if citation is not None)
                t6 = level_determined[2].capitalize()

        # Rest of text
        article_text = ""
        alinea = article.find_all("ALINEA")
        
        #I believe the problem starts here 
        
        for index, p in enumerate(alinea, 1):
            txt = p.find_all("TXT")
            if p.find_previous_sibling():
                # Captures Alinea text of parent
                if p.find_previous_sibling().name == "NO.PARAG":
                    # Used for main text of paragraph
                    if p.contents[0].name == "P":
                        article_text = p.contents[0].text
                        c8 = c7 + '.' + p.find_previous_sibling().text.replace('.', '')
                        parent_citation = c8
                # used for definitions -- do not have a "NO.PARAG" before ALINEA
                article_text = p.text
        txt = p.find_all("TXT")
        for index, t in enumerate(txt, 1):
            if p.find_previous_sibling():
                if t.find_previous_sibling().name == 'NO.P':
                    citation_level_8 = parent_citation + p.find_previous_sibling().text
                    article_text = t.text

        lst.append(
            [c2, t2, c3, t3, c4, t4,
             c5, t5, c6, t6, t7,
             c7, c8, article_text])
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        lst, columns=["T2", "T3", "T4","T5", "T6", "T7", 
                      "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7","C8", "Text"]
    )
```

**Thank you in advance for any help/guidance**

Comment: What's the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: I am not scrapping from a URL. I am scrapping it from an xml file provided above. I am reading in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, pip install lxml
Lib:https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html
My Example, it parse all the levels, just filter out stuff you do not need, quick example: https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/xmlwalk.jpg

Quick example here is that must be refined.

```
# pip install lxml
from lxml import etree as et

def xml_to_dict(xmlfile):
    msg = {}
    count = 1
    with open(xmlfile) as r:
        xml = r.read()
    # print(type(xml))
    parser = et.XMLParser(recover=True, collect_ids=True)
    root = et.fromstring(bytes(xml, encoding="utf-8"), parser)
    x = root.xpath("//*")# get all
    #x = root.xpath("//*[@id]")# get all
    for y in x:
        key = et.QName(y).localname
        print(key)
        value = y.text
        print(value)
        i = y.attrib.get("id")
        print(i)
        # the rest is for making a dict and using it later if needed
        if key in msg:
            key = key + str(count)
            count += 1
        tmp = {key:value}
        msg.update(tmp)
    for k, v in msg.items():
        print(k, ":", v)

#call
xml_to_dict("test.xml")
```

Xml example file

```
{<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <name>Prod</name>
    <sys id="1001">
        <name>sr1</name>
        <task>dest</task>
    </sys>
    <sys id="1002">
        <name>sr2</name>
        <task>dest</task>
    </sys>
    <sys id="1003">
        <name>sr3</name>
        <task>source</task>
    </sys>
</company>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files which you can use to generate a flatter version for Pandas tabular structure. Using the `lxml` third-party library (underlying `'xml'` parser of `BeautifulSoup`), Python can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

And with the `lxml` parser, [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) supports XSLT transformations before parsing into data frames, all for a *single* line of code!

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

- Parses nodes to lowest levels and copies down ancestors, repeating values across nodes (i.e., rows).
- Focuses on three sections: `ALINEA` nodes with a `P` child, `ALINEA` nodes without a `P` child, all `TXT` nodes.
- Uses a `call-template` (similar to Python `def` method) to avoid repetitive code.
- Uses multiple variables with conditional logic to concatenate values.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template name="get_titles">
      <xsl:param name="curr_node"/>
       <xsl:variable name="sect1">
         <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::NO.PARAG">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat('.', translate(preceding-sibling::NO.PARAG, '.', ''))"/>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:variable>
       
       <xsl:variable name="sect2">
         <xsl:if test="ancestor::PARAG/NO.PARAG and name()='TXT'">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat('.', translate(ancestor::PARAG/NO.PARAG, '.', ''))"/>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:variable>
       
       <xsl:variable name="sect3">
         <xsl:if test="name()='TXT'">
           <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::NO.P"/>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:variable>
       
      <Chapter_Title><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::DIVISION/TITLE/TI"/></Chapter_Title>
      <Chapter_Subtitle><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::DIVISION/TITLE/STI"/></Chapter_Subtitle>
      <Article_Title><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ARTICLE/TI.ART"/></Article_Title>
      <Article_Subtitle><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ARTICLE/STI.ART"/></Article_Subtitle>
      <Aline>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::ARTICLE/TI.ART, $sect1, $sect2,  $sect3)"/>
      </Aline>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ALINEA[not(P)]|descendant::ALINEA[P]|descendant::TXT"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ALINEA[P]">
      <row>
        <xsl:call-template name="get_titles"/>
        <TEXT><xsl:value-of select="P"/></TEXT>
      </row>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ALINEA[not(P)]">
      <row>
        <xsl:call-template name="get_titles"/>
        <TEXT><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></TEXT>
      </row>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="TXT">
     <TEXT>
       <xsl:variable name="list">
         <xsl:if test="ancestor::LIST[name(..) != 'ALINEA']">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::LIST/preceding-sibling::P, ' (line break) ', TXT)"/>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:variable>
       
       <xsl:call-template name="get_titles"/>
       <TEXT><xsl:value-of select="concat($list, text())"/></TEXT>
     </TEXT>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH7UDd/2)</kbd>

**Python** *(a single line of code!)*

```py
article_df = pd.read_xml("myInput.xml", stylesheet="myStyle.xsl")
```